# How can I check if a directory contains the same files of a TAR archive?

Tags: command-line, tar, diff

Let's say I have a folder `Documents` and a TAR file `Documents.tar`, how to check if the tar file contains the same files that are present in the directory?

The more obvious solution to me would be to do:

```
$ tar xvf Documents.tar -C untarDocs
$ diff -r Documents untarDocs
```

Unfortunately this is very slow for large TAR files, is there any other alternative?

Using `tar -dvf Documents.tar` (or --diff, --compare) doesn't work because it doesn't detect a file that is present in the filesystem but not in the TAR file, it just detects a file present in the TAR file but not in the filesystem e.g.:

```
$ mkdir new
$ touch new/foo{1..4}
$ tar cvf new.tar new/
$ touch new/bar
$ tar --diff --verbose --file=new.tar       #### doesn't detect new/bar #########
$ rm new/foo1
$ tar --diff --verbose --file=new.tar
```

Output

```
new/
new/foo2
new/foo3
new/foo4
new/foo1
tar: new/foo1: Warning: Cannot stat: No such file or directory   ### works ###
```

Comment: Do you just want to compare file names or also content and metadata?

Comment: @Gilles comparing file names would be enough.

Comment: So see my answer and use `diffopts=`to reduce the amount of meta data to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only to compare lists of file- and directory-names, the `-d` option is not helpful.  Instead, diff'ing sorted lists from `find` and `tar -tf` would do *that*.

Starting with the names assumed in OP's original example:

```
$ tar xvf Documents.tar -C untarDocs
$ diff -r Documents untarDocs
```

here is a suggested script to diff the filenames:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYDIR=$(mktemp -d)
tar tf Documents.tar |sort >$MYDIR/from-tar
find Documents |sort >$MYDIR/from-dir
(cd $MYDIR && diff -r from-tar from-dir)
rm -rf $MYDIR
```

This assumes that `Documents.tar` contains the same top-level "Documents" directory.  If that is not a good assumption, then the lists should be filtered to remove the name of the top-level directory.  OP did not indicate that this would be a problem, however.

In any case, the lists must be sorted, because there is no guarantee which order the `tar` and `find` programs use.

I used [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) because of the clue that OP is using GNU tar (the [**`-d`** option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC66)), which makes it likely on Linux.

There is of course no POSIX tar for reference with regard to `-d`.  [pax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html) does not do diff's either.

Comment: Works great. I am using GNU tar as you assumed.

Comment: With GNU tar 1.28 and GNU findutils 4.7.0, `tar` prints a trailing `/` after directory names but `find` doesn't, so you may want a `sed` in there to remove it before sorting: `tar tf Documents.tar |sed -e 's|/$||g' |sort >$MYDIR/from-dir`

Answer (score -1):

With a standard tar archive, this is not possible. This is because a standard tar archive does not include the list of directory contents.

With the `star` enhacements that are present when star is told to archive everything that is needed for incremental backups, it works:

1) `star -c -dump -C somedir . > /tmp/tarfile`

2) `star -diff -vv -C comparedir < /tmp/tarfile`

You may reduce the amount of metadata that is compare using the `diffopts=` option, see man page.

Comment: Thanks for you answer It provides another approach, but I do not have `star` just `GNU tar` and I must deal with existing `tar` files, so I am not able to reconstruct them.

Comment: Star can easily be compiled from sources, it is maintained since 1982 and there are packages for most existing linux distros. Check: the schily tool bundle at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/